# Matplotlib animation won't save

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I am trying to learn how to create matplotlib animations by using [Jake Vanderplas's basic example](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/), but I'm having trouble getting the figure to save. I installed ffmpeg on my Mac via homebrew.

The only changes that I have made are to add:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TKAgg')
```

When I run this script I receive the following error:

```
anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'extra_args'
```

Based on the many other similar questions, I've tried setting the ffmpeg path with

```
plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path']
```

but that also gives me an error:

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 660, in __setitem__
  See rcParams.keys() for a list of valid parameters.' % (key,))
KeyError: 'animation.ffmpeg_path is not a valid rc parameter.See rcParams.keys() for a list of valid parameters.'
```

After removing the rcParams setting, I also tried adjusting the save command to avoid the aforementioned TypeError:

```
try:
    anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
except TypeError:
    anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', fps=30)
```

This runs with no error, but the mp4 file is not created. I have read over every thread and tried every solution I can find, but nothing changes. The plt.show() call works just fine. Can anyone please point me in the right direction? Thanks!

**Update**: I'm using matplotlib version 1.1.1

Comment: What version of matplotlib do you use?