# Python: Saving animations

Tags: python, python-2.7, animation, matplotlib

I am running a python (2.7.5) script to animate something. The problem is when it comes to saving the file. This is basically the same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27487138/matplotlib-animation-wont-save).

I have followed [this example](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/) with the exception of adding `matplotlib.use('TKAgg')` after `import matplotlib`. Running this will give me the error

```
anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'extra_args'
```

If I remove the `'extra_args'`, the animation will show, but the `.mp4` file is never created. All the `_tmpXXXX.png` files are created (temporarily), but no `.mp4` file is produced.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that it has to do with the version of `matplotlib` python is using. In the above, I am using version 1.1.1, but I need 1.4.3. I followed [these instructions for upgrading](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools/wiki/matplotlib-Installation-Guide-for-Mac-OS-X) `matplotlib`, but python still was not using version 1.4.3.

I used `print matplotlib.__file__` to locate where python was finding `matplotlib`. This directory disagreed with where `pip` placed it, so I simply moved the `matplotlib` v 1.4.3 folder to the directory specified by python. Now it works.